# Java Stream distinctByKey filter with variable arguments

Tags: java, filter, lambda, java-stream, predicate

I have a requirement where I need to get distinct elements from a list and the distinct key fields are variable. I was trying to pass variable argument in distinctByKey but it's not working. Here's what I need to do -

```
   class Pojo {
  final String name;
  final Integer price;
  final String ref1;

  public Pojo(final String name, final Integer price, final String ref1) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.ref1 = ref1;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Integer getPrice() {
    return price;
  }
  
  public String getRef1() {
        return ref1;
      }
```

Following is the code, where I'm trying to get distinct values from the list by passing the distinctByKey arguments as parameters

```
class Test1 {

  public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
  }

  private static List<Pojo> getList() {
    return Arrays.asList(
      new Pojo("123", 100, "A"),
      new Pojo("123", 100, "B"),
      new Pojo("123", 100, "C"),
      new Pojo("456", 200, "D")
    );
  }
  
  private static List<Pojo> ff1 = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {   
      
      ff1.add(getList().get(0));
      ff1.add(getList().get(1));
      ff1.add(getList().get(2));
      ff1.add(getList().get(3));
      
      String key1 = "p.getName() + p.getPrice()" ;

    List<Pojo> f1 =ff1.stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(p -> key1))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
     System.out.println(f1);
```

The intention is if I want to distinctBy ref1, I can do that dynamically.Please suggest how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use reflection, you have to pass a key extractor working with actual getters. A prerequisite to this is that the type of the object is known, which already applies to your case.

```java
List<Pojo> f1 = ff1.stream()
    .filter(distinctByKey(p -> List.of(p.getName() + p.getPrice()))) // key is a String
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

f1.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> Pojo(name=123, price=100, ref1=A)
> Pojo(name=456, price=200, ref1=D)
> ```

The first found and distinct combination of `name` and `price` is present in the list, unless you reimplement the `distinctByKey` method.

---

**Edit:** As Holger [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004446/java-stream-distinctbykey-filter-with-variable-arguments#comment135754603_77004703), it is better using `List` as a key instead of concatenated Strings.

Comment: But as I mentioned my keys could be dynamic. It could be name or name+price or name+price+ref1 or even price+ref1. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Use reflection.

Comment: Don’t use string concatenation to produce a key. It can produce ambiguous keys (`name = "A", price = 123` vs `name = "A1", price = 23`) and it’s inefficient. It’s easy to solve by using, .e.g . `distinctByKey(p -> List.of(p.getName(), p.getPrice()))`

Comment: @Holger: A spot on!